# Ranking order with having same rank repeating to the same level rank category

Tags: mysql, sql

I am little new to sql and I need to rank my votes table based on votes assigned to each person and rank should be same for the similar votes.

My table would be like

```
CREATE TABLE votes ( name varchar(10), votes INT );
INSERT INTO votes VALUES
('Ann',100), ('Jones',151), ('Smith',100), ('Rose',240), ('Lee',500), ('Adhams',500);
```

In my display rows I need to have the rank column first and it should display the rank based on the highest number of votes. Importantly same number of votes need to have the same rank.

I have tried it several times and failed to do it...
Please help me

thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show desired results, particularly, how do the value changes when there are ties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code. There are many links available which would be easily find your answer if you have carefully searched.

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @votes=0;
select x.rank as rank, x.name as name, x.votes as votes 
from(
  select @rank:=if(@votes=votes,@rank, @rank +1)AS rank,
      @votes := votes,
      v.name, 
      v.votes 
    from votes v 
      order by v.votes desc) as x;
```

Comment: @Dilee This answer is not always going to work and will produce incorrect results as the order of column evaluation involving user variables is **non-deterministic**. MySQL has specifically mentioned this in the documentation - **As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.**

Answer (score 3):

To generate `RANK`, you first need a row number in the order of decreasing votes (variable `@rn`) and then based on the previous value of vote, create rank (variable `@rank`).

Try this:

```
SELECT v.*,
    @rank := if((@rn := @rn + 1) is not null,
                if (@votes = votes,
                    @rank,
                    if ((@votes := votes) is not null, @rn, 1)
                    ),1
                ) rank
FROM votes v
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        @votes := NULL, 
        @rank := 0, 
        @rn := 0
    ) t
ORDER BY v.votes DESC;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JYOS65095)

About this:

```
(@rn := @rn + 1) is not null
```

Since, the expression `@rn := @rn + 1` can't be null, we use it to our advantage by not duplicating the whole logic twice.

Comment: User variable order of operations is non-deterministic, is there a possibility this select may give unknown results from time to time?

Comment: @kevingreen - There was an issue previously. I've updated it now. This will work fine always as we are doing all the operations in one go. There is no question of order of operations here. ***The accepted answer will not always work.***

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Can you elaborate what you meant by `(@rn := @rn + 1) is not null` ? I think we can replace this with `@rn := @rn + 1` as the assigned value is always greater than zero ? (since `@rn := 0` initially)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT @rnk := IF(@v = votes, @rnk,
                  IF(@v := votes, @rnk + 1, @rnk + 1) AS rnk
       name, votes
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @v = :0) AS vars
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Comment: Will produce dense rank, not rank